# Tumblr Footer Appears on Desktop, But Not on Tumblr Dashboard and Tumblr Mobile App

Tags: tumblr

I want to place texts at the bottom of each of my Tumblr posts. So I tweaked the HTML of my Tumblr theme.
I was successful in making texts appear on my tumblr posts, but only when opened in my custom domain - and only on desktop. Texts do not appear when viewing posts on Tumblr Dashboard, as well as in Tumblr for mobile.

Comment: This is the correct behaviour. The tumblr dashboard doesn't use your theme html, its independent. For mobile devices, Tumblr will use its own html theme if you have 'Use Optimized Mobile Theme' enabled on the `customise` options.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can edit your own custom mobile theme by creating a "New Page" titled "iphone-theme" and select the "Custom Layout" option.

More details in Tumblr's Custom HTML [FAQ](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#iphonethemes)